# package operation failed 12.04 LTS for 2 weeks now

Tags: 12.04

Ive tried just about everything I could find from multiple forums and I can't find anything that seems to fix the situation. I frequently get messages that interrupt me when I'm browsing and I cant install anything from the Ubuntu Software Center and I'm lucky if I can get the important software updates installed. Message is "Package operation failed" and this is the message:

```
installArchives() failed: Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae (3.2.0-96.136) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to run depmod
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae (--configure):No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae (3.2.0-96.136) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to run depmod
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-96-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Bump since im growing increasingly concerned